# want to pass 4 user inputs to 4 SET commands in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a very basic question about how should I pass 4 parameters from text file to 4 set commands in the batch file.

My Param.txt file contains the following. It is a user input prior to batch run:

```
START_OERIOD=Jan-15
END_PERIOD=Jul-15
RULE_NAME=Multi_LR
FILE_NAME=ACT_multiperiod.txt
```

MY Impot.bat file needs to receive these input as:

```
SET START_PERIOD=Jan-15
SET END_PERIOD=Jul-15
SET RULE_NAME=Multi_LR
SET FILE_NAME=ACT_multi_period.txt
```

I have found many examples of it but am confused, so I am looking for a simple way to do this.

Comment: `for /f` is what you need. What code exactly have you tried that confuses you?

Comment: I have used : for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (Param.txt) do @set %%a=%%b, but don't understand how should i receive the value against each SET command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal:

Param.bat:

```
setlocal
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (Param.txt) do @set %%a=%%b
echo %START_OERIOD%
echo %END_PERIOD%
echo %RULE_NAME%
echo %FILE_NAME%
endlocal
```

Comment: You could actually make that shorter and say `for /f "delims=" %%a in (Param.txt) do set %%a`

Comment: @SomethingDark Yes, it is true... However, I rather set a fix command format `set <expr> = <expr>`, because it won't produce errors even if the equals symbol is missing in some line in the txt file... Also, it is a more readable code.

Comment: Can't argue with that.

Comment: When I use the script given above, it is not showing all 4 parameters. Please look at my batch script:

Comment: @user5578435 I must make clear that I've coded it to be saved into a .bat file and then executed. It is not suitable for direct command-line paste and invocation. Have you pasted it into a .bat file?

Comment: Thanks everyone for help, I could pass the parameters now to my batch file. I had some issues with %% and % and now I have figured out.

Comment: @user5578435 Yes, it is so: In direct command line, FOR parameters placeholders must be written with `%`, but within a batch file they must be written with `%%` (Windows shell standard coding).

Answer (score 1):

simply :

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (param.txt) do set %%a
```